Error while executing command [‘mobile: type’, {‘text’: “S;>[qb’`4=W6p8E)a7h(@F5/{QgRctL<”}]
When I run the following code:
driver.execute_script('mobile: type', {'text': "S;>[qb'`4=W6p8E)a7h(@F5/{QgRctL<"})

I get this error:
File "/Users/amir/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
    raise exception_class(msg=message, stacktrace=format_stacktrace(stacktrace))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/amir/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell "input text \"S;>[qb'\`4=W6p8E)a7h(@F5/{QgRctL<\""' exited with code 1'; Command output: /system/bin/sh: no closing quote

Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/amir/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell "input text \"S;>[qb'\`4=W6p8E)a7h(@F5/{QgRctL<\""' exited with code 1'; Command output: /system/bin/sh: no closing quote

    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:1145:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:491:57)

I realized this error is due to the text itself (S;>[qb’`4=W6p8E)a7h(@F5/{QgRctL<) I send I don’t know!
I think appium can’t insert characters, because when I send text without characters in elements the code works correctly
How can I fix this error and send the characters to the elements in the same way!?
(I don’t want to use the “send_keys” method and I want the text to be sent to the elements using the same method as above.)
All the error is because of this character in parentheses: ( ` )

Why can't you use .send_keys()? You likely need to escape that entire "text" string.
